# ZF2 Doctrine Hydratation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

When I query a table, for example:

```
$query  = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('TaPost')->from("Application\Entity\TaPost", 'TaPost'); 
return $query->getQuery()->getResult()
)
```

I get an array of object "Tapost".

Is there an easy way (and not ruining performance) to get an array of a given new class ? An equivalent to zend/db/sql:

```
new HydratingResultSet(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods(), new myNewClass())
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get directly array result? There are two way. You get an entity object which is `\Application\Entity\TaPost`. You can create a method to your entity like that

```
class TaPost {
    // Your entity attributes and methods
    // ...

    public function toArray()
    {
        return array(
                "id" => $this->getId(),
                "title" => $this->getTitle(),
                "description" => $this->getDescription(),
                // ...
            );
    }
}
```

And use them them when your for loop.

Another solution is, you can use Doctrine `HYDRATE_ARRAY`

```
$results = $query->getQuery()->getResult( Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but that's not exactly my objective.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use doctrine hydrator instead of zend hydrator.

```
$model = new \Blog\Model\Post();
$hydrator = new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($this->getEntityManager(), 'Blog\Model\Post');
$model = $hydrator->hydrate($array, $model);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer but that's not exactly my objective. 
I'm trying to do the [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/zend-db-sql-zend-stdlib-hydrator.html) and, instead of zend-db-sql i'm using Doctrine.

I have a method `findAll()` which have to return an array of objects from class `PostInterface` based on a custom model (post). 
With Doctrine, I get an array of `TaPost` (`TaPost` being an entity of Doctrine) but I need to return an array of `Post`.

How can I tell Doctrine to automatically hydrate `Post` and not `TaPost` ? will i need to made a foreach on my doctrine result and hydrate an object Post one by one ?

ps: with zned-sql, they do it when getting the result:

```
$resultSet = new HydratingResultSet(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods(), new \Blog\Model\Post());

return $resultSet->initialize($result);
```